# Can I save an image that's embedded in an InDesign doc?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to save a current pulse image from some data sheets that were made before I got to this company. Unfortunately no one seems to know where the original image files are, so I'm trying to pull the image directly from the InDesign file.

It's not linked to the file, it's embedded. I tried sifting through the right click options (since that works in Photoshop) but no luck there. I also looked under the Object menu once I had it selected and I'm not seeing anything there either.

Is there a way to pull this image from the file and save it as a PNG without making a screen capture? (since that would be way low res)

Here's some screen caps of what I'm looking at.

[image: The pull in question]

[image: The Right click menu]

EDIT: Just found out that on some of these data sheets, the pulse image was linked but that link is now missing. Anything I can do about that to get the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can un-embed the image from InDesign by right clicking on the link panel and select "Unembed Link".

A dialog box will appear and ask if you want to link to an existing file or create a new file. If you select "No" then you will create a new file for that image on your computer.

There isn't much you can do if the image is not embedded and the link is missing. You can check the path to the missing link and that might give you a clue to where the image might be.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just have to have them remake some of the images since they seem to have vanished. At least now I can save the ones that are embedded.